# How can I calculate the percentage of an outdoor surface that is shaded from the sun using Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a surface in 3D given by a set of points `[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...]` (representing a rock face in my case) and I have the vector of the direction of the sun `[x0,y0,z0]`.

How can I calculate the percentage of the surface that is shaded using Three.js? (Or other library if that's simpler)